# Finding all minimum s t node cuts in a graph with networkx

Tags: graph, networkx

I am using the function `minimum_st_node_cut()` , that find a one set that i need but i need all of posibles sets that verify definition of minimun s t node cut. Please help!! I don't know how to use this function iteratively to find the rest of possible sets.

Comment: Show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate every possible combination of nodes using `itertools.combinations`

Here is an example:

```
from itertools import combinations

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(50, 2, seed=1)

node_combs = list(combinations(G.nodes, 2))

for s, t in node_combs:
    print(minimum_st_node_cut(G, s, t))
```

### But

According to networkX ([docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.cuts.minimum_st_node_cut.html#networkx.algorithms.connectivity.cuts.minimum_st_node_cut)):

> If you need to **compute local st cuts between several pairs of nodes in
> the same graph**, it is recommended that you **reuse the data structures
> that NetworkX uses in the computation**: the **auxiliary digraph** for node
> connectivity and node cuts, and the **residual network** for the
> underlying maximum flow computation.

So, instead you should do it like this:

```
import networkx
from itertools import combinations
from networkx.algorithms.connectivity import build_auxiliary_node_connectivity
from networkx.algorithms.flow import build_residual_network
 
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(50, 2, seed=1)

H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G)
R = build_residual_network(H, "capacity")

# Reuse the auxiliary digraph and the residual network by passing them
# as parameters

node_combs = list(combinations(G.nodes, 2))

for s, t in node_combs:
    print(minimum_st_node_cut(G, s, t, auxiliary=H, residual=R))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I don't need the minimum sets between each pair of nodes, I need to obtain all the sets between two nodes u, v that verify that they are minimum cuts because the `minimum_st_node_cut ()` function returns a single set that is not unique, and I need all the sets.